# How to read GET request parameters in JSF from a redirect

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I need to get input throug form and put the value in Bean field.

After that I want that by pressing a button Bean action will be triggered and when it finished

I need to move to another page by using href.

I tried this:

```
<div class="getname">
    <h:form>
        Enter name
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.name}" />
        <br/>
    </h:form>

    <h:commandButton value="Purchase" action="#{bean.sendName}"/>
    <a href="name.jsf?id=#{bean.id}" />
</div>
```

I manage to move to the right name.jsf page (according to the ID) but the action is not triggered.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `commandButton` component is what will submit the form values to their managed properties.  To do this you must place it inside the `<h:form>` component.

Furthermore, you do not need a seperate link to navigate away from the page after the action is invoked.  A managed bean Action method can return a `String` which is defines the navigation that FacesServlet will FORWARD to.

```
@ManagedBean("bean")
public class MyBean {

  private String id;
  private String name;

  /// property accessors and other stuff

  public String sendName() {
    // do stuff
    return "name.jsf?id=" + this.id;
  }
}
```

When the action is complete this return value instructs to navigate you to that defined view.

Comment: This is what I did before but the problem is that this Bean is @RequestScoped and if I use that kind of nevigation when I move to name.jsf?id= page the content of the bean is being cleaned and I need the content on name.jsf?id= page

Comment: @user1692261 I don't understand... the ID is passed as a request parameter in the URL.  You will be able to fetch it from the request parameter map in the other bean.

Comment: @user1692261.. Does `name.jsf?id` uses a different bean?

Comment: @maple_shaft well, when I do `String Id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");` Id is null. maybe it is beacuse both pages uses the same bean?

Answer (score 0):

Command Button and href are both different actions , click on command button will execute action and click on href will take user to the page name.jsf

```
 <h:commandButton value="Purchase" action="#{bean.sendName}"/>
    <a href="name.jsf?id=#{bean.id}" />
```

You need something like this in your bean

```
@ManagedBean("bean")
public class TestBean {

  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")
  private String id;
  private String name;

  public String sendName() {
     //do stuff 
     return "name.jsf?id=" + this.id;
  }
}
```

You can also do this in your xhtml to get the same outcome,

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Above line will set the parameter id in bean from the request parameter id before your bean is initialized.